The set of the lines tangent to a simple closed loop on the plane is small.
I have a conjecture. It came to me while studying Jordan Curves. It goes as follows:

Given a simple closed loop on the plane, the set of its tangent lines is small (have zero measure).

The space of unoriented lines in the plane is diffeomorphic to the open Möbius band (accordingly to Wikipedia). I'm considering its induced measure. I thought about asking for differentiability, but tangent lines not existing in certain points doesn't seem to be a problem.
The intuition for the result is very clear: if you take a line at random, it will probably not be a tangent line. How to formalize this?
